# double buffering? ... or?

Tags: java, swing, doublebuffered

I uploaded a video of my mini java game - i've tried to catch it as a video.

here the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWQkVivsfbI&feature=youtu.be

so my question: How to handle that bold white stripes while going to the left / up ? When going right or down there is no problem, i think it has to do with double buffering but swing implements double buffering as far as i know and i did this.setDoubleBuffered(true); (my main class is extending JPanel)

Any ideas how to solve? =/

Here is my paint method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(started){
        for(ListIterator<Chunk> it = chunkvector.listIterator();it.hasNext();){
            Chunk r = it.next();
            r.drawChunk(g);
        }

        for(ListIterator<Sprite> it = vectorpainter.listIterator();it.hasNext();){
            Sprite r = it.next();
            r.drawObjects(g);
        }
        for(ListIterator<Animo> it = animovectorpainter.listIterator();it.hasNext();){
            Animo r = it.next();
            r.drawObjects(g);
        }
        //Chat

        if(coni.verified){
        try {
            chat.update(g);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Exception while updating chat! "+e.toString());
        }
        }

        //Framerate Anzeige
        if(fps_on){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString("FPS: "+Integer.toString(fps), 20, 20);
        }
        //Tickberechnung & Anzeige
        tick++;
        if(tick==65536)
                tick=0;
        if(tick_on){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString("Tick: "+Integer.toString(tick),80,20);
        }
    }

}
```

Thats the loader which keeps all the images, :

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class AnimLoader {
    BufferedImage[] chatgui,andi,arrowpic,chunks;

    public AnimLoader(){
        chunks = new BufferedImage[4];
        chunks[0] = loadPics("textures/grass.jpg",1)[0];
        chunks[1] = loadPics("textures/grass1.jpg",1)[0];
        chunks[2] = loadPics("textures/grass2.jpg",1)[0];
        chunks[3] = loadPics("textures/grass3.jpg",1)[0];
        chatgui = loadPics("UI/chatbackground.png",1);
        andi = loadPics("players/andi.gif",1);
        arrowpic = loadPics("objects/arrow.gif",1);
    }

    private BufferedImage[] loadPics(String path, int cnt){
        BufferedImage[] anim = new BufferedImage[cnt];
        BufferedImage source = null;

        URL pic_url = getClass().getResource(path);
        try{
            source = ImageIO.read(pic_url);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        for(int x=0;x<cnt;x++){
            anim[x]=source.getSubimage(x*source.getWidth()/cnt, 0, 
                    source.getWidth()/cnt, source.getHeight());
        }
        System.out.println(pic_url+" - loaded.");
        return anim;        
    }
}
```

And the chunk class :

```
public class Chunk {
private int[][] field;
long x,y;
Game parent;
int size;
//(X|Y) Coordinates from upper left corner of chunk
BufferedImage[] pics;

public Chunk(AnimLoader al,long x, long y, Game p,int size){
    this.size=size;
    field = new int[size][size];
    pics=al.chunks;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.parent= p;
    //StandardInitialising
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            field[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*4);
        }
    }

}

public void drawChunk(Graphics g){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            g.drawImage(pics[field[i][j]],(int) ((50*i)-parent.getplayerx()),(int) ((50*j)-parent.getplayery()),null);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you loading the backgound tile from disk every time? (I reckon so). You should load the background tile into i.e. a byte array

Comment: also... could you show the paint(Graphics g) method

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H58Wv1Uw

here is the paint method.

and i'm loading it into a BufferedImage Object, and later i use this reference to draw

Comment: now can you paste the `drawChunk` method don't use pastebin please

Comment: and the drawObjects method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the only thing I can see is use of iterators (heavy weight object) in a computationally and time sensitive loop (graphics loop). Reduce them to simple fors and cast rather than using iterators. I can only assume that you have a lot of logic between each paint... You need to use bench marking to work out whrer the proceessor is using most of its time and maybe reduce the filesizes. You may also have to introduce some form of clipping engine into your drawing algorithms